# Algebraic Data type scala define constructors

Tags: scala, adt

I'm new to algebraic data type using scala and I have a question:

I want to define type binary, a binary number is presented by a string of "0" & "1" so I need 3 constructors, one to represent the value null, one for the zero and the other for the one.

As we know in algebraic data type a one is a successor of zero and we can write like this

```
one = suc(zero)
two = suc(one)
```

```scala
trait Binary

case class zero extends from Binary // the null value

case class Suc(n: Binary) extends from Binary // the string "0"

// here I need to have the constructor of the number one but I don't know how to do it
case class Suc(Suc(n) : Binary) extends from Binary// but it doesn't seem logic to  me
```

my problem is how to define the one as a case class

waiting for you responses,

thanks in advance

Comment: I think your are mixing two things, you are mixing the concept of numbers in the type level with a simple ADT. Why not just having the three cases _(`null`, `zero` & `one`)_ and then Binary is a NonEmptyList of either _(`zero` or `one`)_.

Comment: can you give me an exemple to illustrate what are you saying please, and to make things clear to me a bit as i said i'm new to the concept of ADT in general

Comment: i undestand a bit what you want to say but i'm confused how to create the one, how to create the constructor of the number one, as you see how i write it i think is not possible, i like the way you see it i think if you give me an exemple i'll understand the problem more and even the logics behind adt, thank you in advance for the comment i apprciate it @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: if you even some references i'll be grateful

Comment: What I mean is that in this case you do not need to use successors, you can just `final case object Zero extends Binary` & `final case object One extends Binary`

Comment: okay, if i use what are you saying how can the one be definded, i mean in Peano numbers, the 1 is the suc of zero and inn you exemple is like i'm having 2 zeros, or are you thinkibg about deine a function where you can fix it, i don't get the idea sorry

Comment: Again you are combining peano numbers with your problem. As you describe your question you do not need one to be defined as a successor of zero. You only need both of them

Comment: Yes you are i get :D thank you

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is often referred to as "Peano numbers."

Here's one implementation.

```
abstract class Nat    //"Nat" for natural numbers
class _0 extends Nat  //or you can use "zero" here
class Succ[N <: Nat] extends Nat
```

And that's all you really need. As the values being represented get higher it becomes more cumbersome to write it all out, `Succ[Succ[Succ[_0]]]`, but that's where type aliases come in handy.

```
type _1 = Succ[_0]
type _2 = Succ[_1]
type _3 = Succ[_2]
type _4 = Succ[_3]
type _5 = Succ[_4]
```

Translating into `case` classes might look something like this:

```
trait Binary
case object Zero extends Binary
case class Suc(n: Binary) extends Binary
val one = Suc(Zero)
val two = Suc(one)   //Suc(Suc(Zero))
// etc.
```